# Pressure equation working to get units kg m/s$^2$, but stuck?

Tags: pressure, unit-conversion

Why does $kg/m^3 \cdot m/s^2 \cdot m$ become $kg\,m/s^2$ (i.e. one newton)

When I do the working, I get $kg/(s^2 m)$ (i.e. metres is on the bottom rather than the top)

My working is:
\begin{align}
    \frac{kg}{m^3} \cdot \frac{m}{s^2} \cdot m&= \frac{kg}{m\cdot m\cdot m} \cdot  \frac{m}{s\cdot s} \cdot  m \\
&= kg \frac{m\cdot m}{m\cdot m\cdot m\cdot (s\cdot s)} \\
&= kg \frac{m^{-1}}{s^2} \\
&= \frac{kg}{s^2 m}
\end{align}
My working for the metre indices: $m^2/m^3 = m^{-1} = 1/m`$

My problem is the metre and its indices. The metre is the opposite way round, but I can't see why. I know the first solution is correct and I am wrong, but I can't see where my working is wrong?

Comment: Normally, I'd say we need to see some context to know what you're referencing. But if you're trying to find pressure, you should know pressure is in units of $N/m^2=kg/(s^2m)$

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the algebra. What is the pressure equation you refer to in the title of your post? $\frac{kg}{s^2 \cdot m}$ is a unit of pressure (the pascal). Multiply the pascal by an area, or $m^2$, to get units of force, $\frac{kg \cdot m}{s^2}$

Comment: Ah, I see now. That makes sense, Jim. It was hydrostatic pressure (density * gravity * depth). I somehow became fixated that HP was only in Newtons and not N/m^2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By multiplying the units you gave in the question, it looks like you're referring to $P=\rho g h$, where $P$ is pressure, $\rho$ is mass density, $g$ is gravitational acceleration, and $h$ is the depth in some fluid (of density $\rho$) at which the pressure is being measured/calculated. Recall that the definition of pressure is force per unit area (as mentioned in the comments above). So, pressure is not the same thing as force. To get a force from a pressure, you have to multiply it (the pressure) by an area (again, as mentioned in the comments above).